# Crazy bug in C, undefined behavior?

Tags: c, undefined-behavior

I am developping a large C code and naturally it crashes at the begining. I found the origine of the bug and it comes from here :

```
printf("%s %d", "\nki2 : ", ki2);
puts("\nline # 1704");
printf("%s %d", "\nki2 : ", ki2);
```

which return in the terminal :

```
ki2 :  237
line # 1704
```

and then crashes with an exit value of -1. Nothing happened between the first access to `ki2` and the second one, so why the programme crashed at the second call of `ki2` and not at the first one ?!

By the way, these lines are executed in a loop and are successfully executed many times before the crash happened.

Is does the same if the print lines are replaced by `printf("\nki2 : %i", ki2);`.

ki2 is an int. Is's value came from another int stored in a dynamic array.

Comment: Nobody can tell for sure, but following might happen here: you mess up something in a part of your code you don't show (buffer overflow, freeing memory not belonging to you, etc.).

Comment: Does the problem still happen if you write the code like this? `printf("\nki2 : %i", ki2);`? **WHAT IS KI2?**

Comment: You also print your new-lines at the beginning, so that the actual line may not be flushed. So the crash may occur after the last `printf`.

Comment: ki2 is an int. It's value came from another int stored in a dynamic array.

Comment: If `ki2` is an int then the problem is in some other code than the code posted.

Comment: "Does the problem still happen if you write the code like this? `printf("\nki2 : %i", ki2);`?" => Yes it still crashes in the same way.

Comment: @Dr.Watson if you can run your program with a debugger, do it. The debugger will show you where the crash happens and maybe even diagnostic other problems before the crash happens.

Comment: "If ki2 is an int then the problem is in some other code than the code posted" : Is there an easy way (debug software) to find it ?

Comment: @Dr.Watson most likely debugging is easy. What is your platform?

Comment: Try this: Add `printf("Done printing ki2\n");` after the second `printf`. It's likely you'll see all lines being printed and then you'll know the the crash happens in some code **after** the posted code.

Comment: @Dr.Watson, yes, there is software that helps you find bugs in your code.  A "debugger", such as has already been suggested to you, is one kind.  If you're using an IDE, then it probably has an integrated one.  If not, then there are standalone debuggers, such as gdb, but which ones are available to you depends on your platform.

Comment: Try running your code through valgrind.  If you're mismanaging memory, it will tell you where.

Comment: 4386427 : Ok I got it, indeed the bug comes from after. Why the last unbugged line was not printed with `printf("%s %d", "\nki2 : ", ki2);` ? 

 Jabberwocky : I used Eclipse and the debbug session was successful. But I just switched to XCode and it seems to find more bugs.

Comment: `printf` writes to `stdout`, which is buffered. It fills an internal buffer until a certain size has been reached or a newline is printed. Put the newlines at the end (how it should be, in my opinion). If you want to print diagnostics for debuging, you can write to the unbuffered error stream `stderr` with `fprintf`.

Comment: _By the way, these lines are executed in a loop and are successfully executed many times before the crash happened._ - Show us the loop.  Are you possibly trying to access past the end of an array somewhere?  Note that UB doesn't have to result in an immediate crash - it can leave your program in a bad state such that it crashes elsewhere.  IOW, the cause may have absolutely nothing to do with the code you've shown.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the last line got stuck in the output buffer. Try

```
printf("%s %d", "\nki2 : ", ki2);
puts("\nline # 1704");
printf("%s %d", "\nki2 : ", ki2);
fflush(stdout);
```

*It's more usual for programs to terminate lines with '\n' rather than start lines with it. You may also try

```
printf("%s %d\n", "ki2 : ", ki2);
puts("line # 1704"); // puts adds '\n' automatically
printf("%s %d\n", "ki2 : ", ki2);
```

Comment: For the @downvoter: `fflush()` prototype is in `<stdio.h>` which the OP has hopefully already included. Also `fflush()` only has [possible] UB when applied to input buffers :)

Comment: I'm also interested in why there's a downvote. Given OP's minimal information, this answer is about the best shot at solving the "problem". Perhaps the downvoter could offer an explanation so we can all learn something?

Comment: @Blaze Downvoting is an anonymous action on SO and several discussions on meta shows that it's how the user wants it to be. So we can never know the real reason for a downvote. In this case my guess is that the DV could be because this is really a "not an answer". OP wants to find out why the program crashes and this answer suggest adding a flush. That won't cure the crash. It's a good advice for further debug but it ain't an answer. Then again... that's just my guess